# Possible to obtain a std::vector<T>::const_iterator from a multi index container index?

Tags: boost, stl, boost-multi-index

I am converting some code in a system that serves the UI with an enumerator. Unfortunately the enumerator has been designed around the `std::vector<T>::const_iterator`. That is, it takes a begin and end iterator of type `std::vector<T>::const_iterator`.

I would like to convert the underlying container of the data source from a vector to a boost multi index container. This works well, until I have to serve the enumerator.

My question is, is it possible to convert a multi index container index iterator to a `std::vector<T>::const_iterator`?

Comment: Oops. There's your reason not to use implementation details in an interface. If you are lucky (depending on the element type of the vector, e.g.) you might be able to forge a hybrid using Boost Intrusive using the vector as backing. (This requires you to alter the element type with hooks for Boost Intrusive though.)

Comment: On the implementation details in an interface - I couldn't agree with you more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible; vectors are contiguous containers, but even random access indices do not provide data contiguity.

You'll need either to keep indices external to the vector, or recreate the vector as required.